# Ubuntu installation won't work on crashed windows laptop

Tags: boot

So I have a Windows 8 laptop that I'm trying to renovate, but the Windows 8 crashed, and won't boot. I decided to install Ubuntu on it instead using a Live CD on a usb stick, and proceeded to boot the cd, and go through the installation process, I selected LVM installation and clicked install, and get the following error: `The efi file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed.` I couldn't find anything on it, and was wondering if someone could help. Sorry about the bad wording, I suck at writing things, Thanks.

Comment: What is your intention?  To "rescue" your Windows 8 installation?  Or do you want to replace Windows with Ubuntu?  Your system stopped working before you ever tried to install Ubuntu -- could you have dead or dying hardware?  If you want to wipe the laptop, and install Ubuntu - I suggest that you use "Disks" in the live environment to format your hard drive **before** you reboot and try the installation.  No sense in trying to perform a clean installation on top of a possibly dirty/corrupted base.

Answer (score 0):

Flying guesses:

1. Secure boot may be a thing. I'd keep it enabled if possible, but try disabling it in the EFI options.
2. The storage device you are using could be bad. It may be something simple, but if you don't care about the data, try to fully reformat the drive, and let Ubuntu's installer handle everything for you. You can always go back and tinker if you get it to actually work with the simplest settings.
3. The options you selected are incompatible with the drive's current situation. This may be that you are trying to install something alongside something else when you really meant to destroy the drive's contents.

One easy way around a bad drive is to replace it with a cheap drive from somewhere like Microcenter. SSDs are around 20 dollars-ish now. I wouldn't (necessarily) use it in a desktop, or high-end laptop, but they're not bad now for something cheap. That may require more hardware work than you're comfortable with, though.

It wasn't clear if you were trying to install onto the USB stick from a physical CD, if that's true, it may be possible to get things rolling by disabling the internal drive in the EFI settings.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help!